# Filename too long - IMPOSSIBLE to delete/move/rename

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I can`t delete a folder because it has LOTS of folders inside it. Believe me, it is really lots.

`(E:\Backups\john\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\USERDA~1\Default\PLUGIN~1\GOOGLE~1\MAILGO~1.COM\HTTPS_~1\GOOGLE~1\41\67\34\0\69\24\78\58\62\64\5\45\81\27\61\91\95\42\27\36\91\4\2\53\92\82\21\16\18\95\47\26\71\38\69\12\67\99\35\94)`

The path is even longer...

I have tried several ways for deleting it: "Unlocker Tool", "rd /s" in Command Prompt, "subst x: e:\backups\john" in Command Prompt, no one was effective.

It's IMPOSSIBLE to rename/move files.

I don't want to break up anything, so please think through your answer.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `rm` utility in my [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm).  I wrote it using the new [long Unicode filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) format interally, so if the problem is just that the name is too long, this should get it.  It sounds like this is a one-time thing, so the [free demo version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm) is all you need.  If you don't want it afterward, it uninstalls cleanly in seconds.

If you try it and it *doesn't* work, please tell me as I'd like to fix it so it will.

Comment: Oh Nicole...I hope so...I'll try it and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: I have just tried your software. Following is the command tried and the answer given: -- 9 C% rm -rf E:\Backups\john
hrm:  Couldn't remove directory 'E:\Backups\john\Users\john'.

Comment: I was doing many attempts with many softwares and tricks and I just realized that the inconvenient folder wasn't there anymore. I can't tell if your software or another trick did the job. Anyway I'm voting your answer as effective. I appreciate your attention and I was really amazed when I first saw that you develop your own softwares. Thank you. Keep yourself on your good way and your job. Have a blessed 2013!

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved.  It'd be nicer if I could be sure I could take credit.  If you have occasion to use my C shell again and one of the utilities complains, type `help` immediately afterward and it'll tell you the status code and reason.  The most common reasons `rm` might fail would be an ACL that denies you access or that it's in use by another process.

Comment: Sure. I really appreciate your attention and I believe you can take the credits...unless the "subst x: e:\backups\john" (in Command Prompt) had did the trick, then your software did. I'm not sure because I was quite disappointed of doing searches and tests and not getting my problem solved. Anyway everything points to your solution. - Thank you!

Comment: I will recommend your software to everyone needing a decent DOS system or having this problem.

Comment: Thank you, Darkeden.  From what you've told me, I'm guessing `rm` deleted everything in that directory but couldn't delete the root because it was in use by another process, perhaps as the current directory for that other process.  If it had failed deeper in the directory tree, that's what `rm` would have said.

Comment: Hi Nicole; having the same problem, and I'm getting the following error, with rm -rf directory   "The directory is not empty".  I thought that the -rf arguments would take care of this?

Comment: Hi, Adam.  The `-f` options tells `rm` it can remove read-only files and directories, just like on Unix or Linux.  But Windows files and directories can also be marked as Hidden and System. You can see these attributes with `ls -l` or just `ll`.  Hidden files can be removed with `-H`.  System files can be removed with `-S`.  If you don't care what it is, just remove it, use `-x`.  If this doesn't solve your problem, please ping me again.  (I check email constantly, here, not so regularly.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this will sound cumbersome, but I have had success with this process.

- Boot to Safe Mode
- Attempt to delete the item while in Safe Mode.
- If this FAILS, stay in Safe Mode and drop to a command prompt
- Change directories all the way to the end of the path in question.
- Do a `DIR /A:H` to show in hidden files
- using the command prompt, delete all files in this directory
- Move up one level in the directory structure, repeat the DIR /A:H and deletion process
- Keep moving up until the total path name is less than 254 characters in length. Then you should be able to delete everything from a point higher up in the folder hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your attention Chris, but I could get rid off this issue already. Nicole Hamilton's sfotware did the trick for me. Since it's solved I won't be able to say if your process would work or not. All I can tell is that I have tried really several ways for deleting it. I have even tried to delete into Safe Mode, not exactly on your way, but closer. As you can see in my question, the path is extremely long, so it was hard and boring to access a folder with any files. That's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Split the folder, but copy it to drive `C` or something else, not to the other folder.

Then you can delete it.